# verilog: how do I add parameters

Tags: verilog, xilinx

I want to have parameterized module. It has the following definition:

```
module example (...);
    parameter A = 2;
    parameter B = 2;
    parameter C = A + B;

endmodule
```

However, when I print out the parameter values, I get A = 2, B = 2, and C = 1... Any ideas why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution - use localparam.

```
module example (...);
  parameter A = 2;
  parameter B = 2;
  localparam C = A + B;

endmodule
```

Comment: In fact in your original question, C should be equal to 4. However, it is dangerous and very possible to be overrided because C is a parameter. Using localparam is the right way to define a parameter which cannot be override by defparam or instance parameter value assignments.

Comment: Except localparams can not be used for port lists, using verilog-2001 style port declarations.